# Docker chain in iptables overrides INPUT rules

Tags: docker, iptables

I have a server and I am running a few docker containers. These containers have a few ports that aren't open. I have added INPUT rules to only allow access to those ports from 1 ip and after that I have a DROP rule.

This should block all access to the ports from except my home ip. Now it turns out that docker just allows everything and docker somehow is able to override the input rules because the input rules are not working.

I believe this has to do with the FORWARDING rule which looks like this:

`Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhereACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere`

I have flushed all the rules and then I get really wierd errors from docker things like:

`driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint gogs (b62814647bf440e923c009da0ca76185fac2f89a9534eb11792dbcb07ef3ffbf):  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t filter -A DOCKER ! -i br-5dd41982af68 -o br-5dd41982af68 -p tcp -d 172.18.0.6 --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

How can I make sure that the input rules override everything so that the port filtering on the INPUT chain stop access for everybody else but me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a way better option. Avoid the DOCKER-USER all together.

I realized that what I want to protect is the network card interface. So lets say I have a VPS and it has an interface eth0 that connects to the internet then all I need to do is block all incoming traffic for eth0 except the ports I want. For example 80, 443. I can then also add IP exceptions for eth0 like my home and office ipnumbers. I then allow everything else.

So in short block the internet interface except certain ports and allow everything else.

Example bash file that I use to quickly set my iptable rules:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set temporary all to accept otherwise the next flush might block us out
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

# Flush all the existing rules
iptables -F

# Allow internal connections. 
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow established connections
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow IP address
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s IP
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s IP -j ACCEPT

# Allow http and https
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Block all on eth0 or any other 
#iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
#iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j DROP

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. It turns out that the INPUT chain is skipped and instead the FORWARDING chain is used for docker. The first rule of the FORWARDING chain is to read the DOCKER-USER chain. That chain will contain docker rules that aren't overridden by docker.

Let's say you want to your home ip to access certain ports and block them for everybody else. Use these 2 rules:

```
iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -s YOURIP -p tcp -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 8000:10000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 5000:9999 -j DROP
```

Also you need to use the ctorigdstport param since there is a form of nat translation going on and dport param won't work.

Comment: Note that `--ctorigdstport` matches the original destination port of the *first packet* of the connection (tracked by `conntrack`), not the packet being filtered! So the dropping rule will also drop responses to the *outgoing* connections from Docker to the world on 5000-9999! Add `--ctdir ORIGINAL` to the DROP rule to match only incoming packets. See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22054#issuecomment-466663033

Comment: For the sake of clarity, what you refer by "FORWARDING" is the "FORWARD" chain?

Comment: FORWARD is quite different from INPUT. The packages that end up in the INPUT chain of the filter table are not forwarded anywhere, they're targeted at the host itself. So I don't see how you're fixing the problem stated in the title. You're just solving your issue (which is good for you, of course).